# Python script says The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, automation

Hi so i'm trying to make a python script to do some automation to generate a file from some tools(can't name them but the commands will give you an idea) and while I made a script that passes commands to cmd/terminal (cmd in mycase) using os.system like given below

```
os.system('"' + dc_dir + '" --scan "' + in_dir + '" --out "' + out_dir + '\\'+ Project_name + '.csv' + '" --format CSV --enableExperimental')

and it returns "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."

but when i print the exact same line and run it manually it works

print('"' + dc_dir + '" --scan "' + in_dir + '" --out "' + out_dir + '\\'+ Project_name + '.csv' + '" --format CSV --enableExperimental')
```

this is the command printed

```
"C:\SBOM\dependency-check-6.2.2\bin\dependency-check.bat" --scan "C:\FinalScript\Source Codes\Sireous" --out "C:\SBOM\SiriusProgrammer_2_0.csv" --format CSV --enableExperimental
```

please help me out with this if possible.

Comment: try using double slashes for windows paths  i.e. ```--scan "C:\\FinalScript\\Source Codes\\SiriusProgrammer_2_0 ...```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try to localize the problem. To do so we need to re-organize your code a bit:

1. It is not how we concatenate strings nowadays. That's the way:

   ```py
   dc_dir = 'C:\\SBOM\\dependency-check-6.2.2\\bin\\dependency-check.bat'
   in_dir = 'C:\\FinalScript\\Source Codes\\'
   out_dir = 'C:\\SBOM\\'
   Project_name = 'SiriusProgrammer_2_0'

   f'{dc_dir} --scan {in_dir}{Project_name} --out {out_dir}{Project_name}.csv --format CSV --enableExperimental'
   ```
2. It is better to use libraries dedicated to specific task. pathlib will help you to avoid escape clattering.

   ```
   from pathlib import Path

   project_name = 'SiriusProgrammer_2_0'
   project_dir = Path('C', 'SBOM')

   dependency_check_bat = project_dir.joinpath('dependency-check-6.2.2', 'bin', 'dependency-check.bat')
   source_code_dir = Path('C', 'FinalScript', 'Source Codes', project_name)

   f'{dependency_check_bat.as_posix()} --scan {source_code_dir.as_posix()} --out {project_dir.joinpath(project_name).as_posix()}.csv --format CSV --enableExperimental'
   ```
3. As for the main problem, I suggest using subprocess, which is handy if you want to pass variables to the script:

   ```py
   import subprocess

   process_run = subprocess.Popen([dependency_check_bat.as_posix(),
                                   '--scan',
                                   source_code_dir.as_posix(),
                                   '--out',
                                   f'{project_dir.joinpath(project_name).as_posix()}.csv',
                                   '--format CSV',
                                   '--enableExperimental'],
                                   stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

   terminal_output = process_run.communicate()[0]
   print(terminal_output)
   ```

Let's do this and see what terminal will return to us.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Make syntax clean with the help of **f-string**

```
os.system(f'{dc_dir} --scan {in_dir} --out {out_dir}\{Project_name}.csv --format CSV --enableExperimental')
```